# How to add a UITextField to UIToolbar with flexible width in iOS 11 using auto-layout

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, nslayoutconstraint, uitoolbar, ios11

I want to add a UITextField to a UITooolbar and let the UITextField expand its width as needed to fill the area, like a UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace does.

Below is a snippet about how i normally set up a toolbar items in a view controller ...

```
// two UIBarButtonItems
UIBarButtonItem *left = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *right = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

// the UIBarButtonItem with a UITextField as custom view
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
UIBarButtonItem *text = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:textField];

[self setToolbarItems:@[left, text, right]];
```

... which will then show up like this.

[image: ios11_toolbar]

Before iOS 11 i sub-classed UIToolbar and used the layoutSubviews method to get the width (`CGRectGetWidth(itemView.frame)`) for all 'non-flexible' items and calculate the available width for the textfields view frame.
With iOS 11, Apple changed to auto-layout all bars as mentioned at [WWDC2017 session 204](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/204/) and now the `CGRectGetWidth(itemView.frame)` way will not provide a valid width until the view is visible which was also pointed out at [iOS 11 UIBarButtonItem images not sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46247451/ios-11-uibarbuttonitem-images-not-sizing).

How can i now add flexible sized UIBarButtonItems with customViews using constraints and auto-layout which will expand to fill the complete free area between two items?

**EDIT 1:**

If i add only the textfield the item will expand its width as expected.

[image: ios11_toolbar_textfield_only]

**EDIT 2:**

Using constraints within the UIToolbar directly seems to be impossible as the item views are non existent (until they are placed?) or do not have a superview.

```
UIBarButtonItem *left = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:nil];
UIView *leftView = [left valueForKey:@"view"];
UIBarButtonItem *right = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
UIView *rightView = [right valueForKey:@"view"];

UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
UIBarButtonItem *text = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:textField];

NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(leftView, textField, rightView);
NSString *formatString = @"|-[leftView]-[textField]-[rightView]-|";

NSArray *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:formatString options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:nil views:views];
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:constraint];

[self setToolbarItems:@[left, text, right]];
```

**EDIT 3:**

With the idea on checking the [view hierarchy for UIToolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46581263) i ended up with the following piece of code to add constraints ...

```
// _UIToolbarContentView
//   + _UIButtonBarStackView
//       + _UIButtonBarButton
//       + UIView
//       + _UITAMICAdaptorView
//       + UIView
//

UIView *contentView = nil;
for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.toolbar.subviews) {
    if ([view.description containsString:@"ContentView"]) {
        contentView = view;
    }
}

UIView *stackView = nil;
for (UIView *view in contentView.subviews) {
    if ([view.description containsString:@"ButtonBarStackView"]) {
        stackView = view;
    }
}

// constrain views on stack
UIView *uiButtonBarButton = [stackView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
[uiButtonBarButton.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:stackView.leadingAnchor].active = YES;

UIView *uiTAMICAdaptorView = [stackView.subviews objectAtIndex:2];
[uiTAMICAdaptorView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:uiButtonBarButton.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
[uiTAMICAdaptorView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:stackView.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
```

... which will change the view like this:

[image]

Why is the UIBarButton getting resized and not the UITextField aka UITAMICAdaptorView?

Fixing the size for UIBarButton with a constraint ...

```
[uiButtonBarButton.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:CGRectGetWidth(uiButtonBarButton.frame)].active = YES;
```

... looks like ...

[image]

... but unfortunately the frame of UIButtonBarButton is not valid until the item is placed.

So how to constrain the UIButtonBarButton in its width without knowing it. Something like 'notGreaterThanNecessary'?

Comment: I had a similar question and wrote something as solution. Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46581263

Comment: @lucasl This is not exactly what i am looking for but the idea on traversing the toolbars subviews is great. I edited my question with the new knowledge.

Comment: Starting iOS 11, UIBarButtonItems added to a UIToolBar no longer have a superView so we can't set their constraints when the view is loaded

Comment: @mnabaa As i unterstand, before iOS 11 these Items don't have a superView but they are still views and we can set their size. Starting iOS 11 these items views are sized and placed by using auto-layout which is only possible on views. As pointed in the question each item is a view placed in a stackView. But until now i could not find a way to change these 'system constraints' for margins, width and high.

Comment: @grethi have you fixed this issue? If yes, how did you do that?

Answer (score 3):

Put a single UIView directly into a single UIBarButtonItem, this will become the full width of the UIToolBar.

Now you can add whatever subviews you want using layout constraints as normal. A horizontal UIStackView will work very nicely here.