# UIButton tap area got smaller on iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, ios11, xcode9, uiedgeinsets

I notice the tap area for my UIButton got smaller since iOS 11. To confirm, I commented out the desired background color on its subviews and put purple color on the button itself.

iOS 10.0.3 (Button shown as desired)
[image]

iOS 11.1 (Tap area got smaller)
[image]

My code follows.

```
UIImage *ringImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball20r"];
UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10,10,10,10); //padding
UIImage *stretchableImage = [ringImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:insets];

UIImageView *imageView   = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:stretchableImage];
// imageView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor; //disabled for testing
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, label.frame.size.width + 16.0, label.frame.size.height + 16.0);
[imageView addSubview:label];


label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"label":label};
NSArray *constraint_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(8)-[label]-(8)-|"
                                                                options:0
                                                                metrics:nil
                                                                  views:viewsDictionary];
NSArray *constraint_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(8)-[label]-(8)-|"
                                                                options:0
                                                                metrics:nil
                                                                  views:viewsDictionary];
[imageView addConstraints:constraint_H];
[imageView addConstraints:constraint_V];


UIButton *calendarButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[calendarButton addTarget:self action:@selector(chooseACalendarToSave) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
calendarButton.frame = imageView.frame;
[calendarButton addSubview:imageView];

//added for testing only
calendarButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];

_calendarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:calendarButton];
```

How can I make the area for iOS just like iOS 10.0.3 and earlier?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here.
[iOS 11 UIBarButtonItem images not sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46247451/ios-11-uibarbuttonitem-images-not-sizing)

```
 if (@available(iOS 9, *)) {
      [cButton.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant: standardButtonSize.width].active = YES;
      [cButton.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant: standardButtonSize.height].active = YES;
 }
```

As soon as I inserted above code, the button started working as expected. Thank you.